# Using "mov ax, code" in COM-file

Tags: assembly

Here is my code(I use TASM)

```
CODE SEGMENT                  
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:CODE, SS:CODE

org 256     
;------start-------
STARTPROC       PROC
        mov ax, CODE
        ret
STARTPROC       ENDP    

CODE ENDS
        end STARTPROC
```

The line "mov ax, CODE" cause error in TLINK - "Cannot generate COM file : segment-relocatable items present".
I don't understand why it is bad? I use only one segment.

Comment: `mov ax, CODE` does not make any sense. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: @nrz I know. I would like to understand why it cause an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .com executable file is a very simple file format, it cannot have any segments.  It starts up with all segment registers set to the one-and-only segment, the value is unpredictable.

Trying to refer to a segment like you did gives the linker a heart attack, you ask it to predict the unpredictable.  That can only work in a relocatable executable, a .exe.  That's an executable file format that also contains a list of locations in the code that need to be adjusted for the load address of the segments.  The .exe file is written as though every segment loads at 0000:0000.  The operating system loader determines where every segment actually gets loaded at runtime.  And walks that table, patching the code to add the segment load address.  Then starts the program.  This cannot work in a .com file, it doesn't have that table.

Comment: Right. `mov ax, cs` should do what you want, without any relocations.